# What are my options for sending email from my VPS with a Blacklisted IP

Tags: postfix, spf, gmail, blacklist

I have postfix and dovecot running on debian 7, I can send mail fine, but it keeps going to my spam folder when sent to google accounts. Another user who doesn't use gmail said it was delivered to his inbox. When I send a test message to myself I get the following headers:

```
Delivered-To: chaoskreator@gmail.com
Received: by 10.170.37.203 with SMTP id 194csp288892ykf;
        Fri, 29 Aug 2014 21:45:25 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.236.70.105 with SMTP id o69mr20864964yhd.25.1409373925239;
        Fri, 29 Aug 2014 21:45:25 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <webmaster@beansworthy.fluidvector.com>
Received: from fluidvector.com ([2605:f700:100:400::875a:4b61])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id s36si567167yhp.30.2014.08.29.21.45.24
        for <chaoskreator@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 29 Aug 2014 21:45:24 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning webmaster@beansworthy.fluidvector.com does not designate 2605:f700:100:400::875a:4b61 as permitted sender) client-ip=2605:f700:100:400::875a:4b61;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning webmaster@beansworthy.fluidvector.com does not designate 2605:f700:100:400::875a:4b61 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=webmaster@beansworthy.fluidvector.com
Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by fluidvector.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 725E7123A0C9F
    for <chaoskreator@gmail.com>; Sat, 30 Aug 2014 00:45:23 -0400 (EDT)
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at fluidvector.com
Received: from fluidvector.com ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (fluidvector.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id oI9bUVMx6Thv for <chaoskreator@gmail.com>;
    Sat, 30 Aug 2014 00:45:19 -0400 (EDT)
Received: by fluidvector.com (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id 17DA0123A0CA1; Sat, 30 Aug 2014 00:45:19 -0400 (EDT)
To: =?UTF-8?B?dGVzdA==?= <chaoskreator@gmail.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?V2VsY29tZSB0byAiQmVhbnNXb3J0aHki?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:messenger.php
From: <webmaster@fluidvector.com>
Reply-To: noreply@fluidvector.com
```

I notice the lines

```
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning webmaster@beansworthy.fluidvector.com does not designate 2605:f700:100:400::875a:4b61 as permitted sender) client-ip=2605:f700:100:400::875a:4b61;
    Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
           spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning webmaster@beansworthy.fluidvector.com does not designate 2605:f700:100:400::875a:4b61 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=webmaster@beansworthy.fluidvector.com
```

which I assume means there's an issue with my SPF TXT DNS record: `v=spf1 a:fluidvector.com ~all`, even though pySPF says it's good.

I've looked up on mxtoolbox.com and found that for some reason, my IP (which I obtained from my VPS provider) is apparently blacklisted on Barracuda and spamcannibal. I've contacted my VPS provider, but they didn't seem to be able to do anything for me. So, at this point I assume I'm limited to just contacting the black lists and pleading to have my IPs removed? What are my options here? Can I get gmail to let mail from my servers be delivered to inbox instead of the spam folder without the headache of trying to get unlisted?

Comment: Is your question about the SPF-Softfail or the Blacklists? Concerning the SPF-Error you seem to be using both `fluidvector.com` and `beansworthy.fluidvector.com` (and btw also `mail.fluidvector.com`) which may cause the error. More info (logs, config) are needed to clarify this.

Comment: Your IPv6 address was not on any blacklists according to mxtoolbox. You simply forgot to add it to your SPF record.

Answer (score 0):

IPs that have been blacklisted can be difficult to unlist because even if you can fix the ones you've listed; there maybe many other blacklist servers that will block you and every company can maintain their own blacklists. If you have an established business they might work with you but they might just deny your request.

The easiest way to solve this issue is to **use a 3rd Party email service** like SendGrid. If you are only sending transactional email you can use Postmark or Mandrill. You can send hundreds of emails a month with Sendgrid for $1.  You'll be able to add them to your SPF record and it will significantly improve your deliverability.